# select distinct sumof from mysql query with having

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, having

```
table structure 
=====================================================================
id |fee_amount|fee_paid|fee_type|fee_user|date         | Fee_for
=====================================================================
1  | 2000     | 500    | REG    | 105    | 01.02.2017  | FEB
-----------------------------------------------
2  | 2000     | 1000   | REG    | 105    | 03.02.2017  | FEB
-----------------------------------------------
3  | 2000     | 500    | REG    | 105    | 04.02.2017  | FEB
-----------------------------------------------
4  | 1000     | 500    | FEE    | 105    | 10.03.2017  | MAR
-------------------------------------------------------------
5  | 1000     | 500    | FEE    | 105    | 11.03.2017  | MAR
--------------------------------------------------------------
6  | 1000     | 1000   | FEE    | 105    | 13.03.2017  | APR
```

From the above I am saving the fee paying details

one student is paid the amount as partially on the above values

using this I need to get the total fees and total paid fees and the balance need to pay

for this I used

```
SELECT SUM(fee_amount) as fee, SUM(fee_paid) as paid ,fee_type
FROM tbl_fee A WHERE fee_user='105'
                group by fee_type
                having SUM(fee_amount)!=(SUM(fee_paid)
```

But its getting

```
6000  | 2000 | REG
2000  | 1000 | FEE
```

I need to get

```
2000  | 2000 | REG
1000  | 1000 | FEE
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SELECT fee_amount as fee, SUM(fee_paid) as paid ,fee_type
FROM tbl_fee A WHERE fee_user='105'
                group by fee_type
                having fee_amount!=(SUM(fee_paid) , it will solve your problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query to get the result that you need

```
SELECT fee_amount as fee, SUM(fee_paid) as paid ,fee_type FROM tbl_fee A WHERE fee_user='105' group by fee_type
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to sum the `fee_amount` field, then simply do not sum it up, but either include it in the `group by` clause or use the `any_value()` function to make your query compliant with the sql standard:

```
SELECT fee_amount as fee, fee_type, SUM(fee_paid) as paid
FROM tbl_fee A
WHERE fee_user='105'
group by fee_type, fee_amount
```

Obviously, these solutions assume that `fee_amount` is the same within a fee_type for all users. If the `fee_amount` can be different within a fee type and a user, then you need to specify how to handle such situations.